# Matrix $A,B$ are given and matrix $C$ is arbitrary , if $AC=CA\Rightarrow BC=CB$,show there is a polynomial $f$ and $f(A)=B.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A,B\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C}).$ If for any $C\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with property $AC=CA$,then we can have $BC=CB.$How to show there is a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $f(A)=B$?Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Do you mean " then we have $CB = BC$"? Another little language thing, we say that a matrix commutes with another matrix, not that it is commutative with another matrix. Commutative describes a set, not a single element.

Comment: @RichardJensen Yes,I made a typo.I have adjusted it.

Comment: This is a special case of the [double centraliser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem). A proof can be found in [a paper by Lagerstrom](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-08/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4.pdf). The are probably simpler proofs

Comment: If I remember correctly, the "easy" proof is essentially as follows: it is easy to show that if there is a polynomial $f$ for which $f(A) = B$, then $CB = BC$ whenever $CA = AC$. After making this observation, show that the dimension of the subspace spanned by the powers of $A$ has the same dimension as the space of $B$ for $CA = AC \implies CB = BC$. These dimensions can be counted with the careful usage of Jordan form.

Comment: @user1551 I'm not sure that any of the forms of the double centraliser theorem mentioned on the Wikipedia page are directly applicable here. The Lagerstrom proof is nice though.